# Grpc-java multiple channel management

Tags: java, netty, grpc, http2

I am using grpc-java (netty) for my client-server communication. Currently, I am using NettyChannelBuilder to create a single channel (which is backed by a single http2 connection i believe) and I use the channel to create all my GRPC stubs.
Since the RPS is quite high, I see the a saturation of the grpc channel and requests are starting to queue up. I would like to create more channel (hence naturally more connections). Is there a way to achieve that?

In addition is my assumption that a grpc channel is backed by a single http2 connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should make client channel's thread pool more bigger.

The channel can have many subchannel, and a subchannel has one or many transport, a transport represent a connection. And a server address usually has one connection.

```java
 ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("127.0.0.1", 9091)
                      .executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool())
                      .usePlaintext()
                      .build()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. Could you explain or give pointers as to how to expand the channels connection size?

Answer (score 0):

A gRPC channel is backed by one or more sub-channels; each sub-channel being a connection. Having more connections helps when you have multiple servers (backends) so each connection goes to a different backend. If you have a single server (backend) you should ensure that creating multiple connections to the same server will actually help which would be the case if the server is not the bottleneck and is able to process high network throughput.

The creation of multiple sub-channels in a channel happens using a [RoundRobinLoadBalancer](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/util/src/main/java/io/grpc/util/RoundRobinLoadBalancer.java) and something called [EquivalentAddressGroup](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/api/src/main/java/io/grpc/EquivalentAddressGroup.java). To create multiple sub-channels to the same server you have to be able to create multiple `EquivalentAddressGroup`s for the same server. A custom  [NameResolver](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/api/src/main/java/io/grpc/NameResolver.java) (or [DnsNameResolver](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/grpc/internal/DnsNameResolver.java)) will be needed to do this.

Comment: sorry bro but github ultil RoundRobinLoadBalancer is 404 - page not found. Can you resend the link?

Comment: fixed the link.